# Airflow 2 error, Registering operators or sensors in plugins is deprecated

Tags: airflow

Trying to upgrade to Airflow 2 and doing the `airflow upgrade_check` I have the following error:
**FutureWarning: Registering operators or sensors in plugins is deprecated -- these should be treated like 'plain' python modules, and imported normally in DAGs.**

Below is where the class is coming from, within the  _ *init* _.py file:

```
from airflow.plugins_manager import AirflowPlugin
   
from bigquery_plugin.operators import BigQueryOperator
    
        
   class AirflowSnowflakePlugin(AirflowPlugin):
        # The name of your plugin (str)
        name = 'bigquery_plugin'
        # A list of class(es) derived from BaseOperator
        operators = [BigQueryOperator]
        # A list of class(es) derived from BaseSensorOperator
        sensors = []
        # A list of class(es) derived from BaseHook
        hooks = [BigQueryHook]
        # A list of class(es) derived from BaseExecutor
        executors = []
        # A list of references to inject into the macros namespace
        macros = []
        # A list of objects created from a class derived
        # from flask_admin.BaseView
        admin_views = []
        # A list of Blueprint object created from flask.Blueprint. For use
        # with the flask_admin based GUI
        flask_blueprints = []
        # A list of menu links (flask_admin.base.MenuLink). For use with the
        # flask_admin based GUI
        menu_links = []
        # A list of dictionaries containing FlaskAppBuilder BaseView object
        # and some metadata. See example below
        appbuilder_views = []
        # A list of dictionaries containing FlaskAppBuilder BaseView object
        # and some metadata. See example below
        appbuilder_menu_items = []
```

Is it saying I can remove this entirely from my _ *init* _.py? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `BigQueryOperator` from operators. You can use it without

Operators and Sensors should no longer be registered or imported via Airflow's plugin mechanism -- these types of classes are just treated as plain python classes by Airflow, so there is no need to register them with Airflow.

**Before**:

```py
from airflow.operators.bigquery_plugin import BigQueryOperator
```

**You should instead import it as**:

```py
from bigquery_plugin.operators import BigQueryOperator
```

Check: https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/a17db7883044889b2b2001cefc41a8960359a23f/UPDATING.md#adding-operators-and-sensors-via-plugins-is-no-longer-supported

Comment: thanks for responding! I currently have from bigquery_plugin.operators import BigQueryOperator already in my question. But when you say: 'Remove BigQueryOperator from operators. You can use it without' do you mean remove operators = [BigQueryOperator] so its just operators = [ ]

Comment: yup i.e. don't use Plugin mechanism for it. Use `from bigquery_plugin.operators import BigQueryOperator` in your DAG directly (not plugin)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [this](https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/12069/commits/90b1128cb7f4b3a07c27aaaa0b330d5415bbffc7#diff-7bfb481064cd476fafe05437d31ba297c9255c13cac38d6f2d2aaeed64af7e13) pull request you can see that the specific issue that `Registering operators or sensors in plugins is deprecated` is logged at this scenario:

> props.get('operators', []) or props.get('sensors', []):

So, in your case, as mentioned on the comment above you should have empty list of operators defined in the plugin.